# Pandas read_csv fails on first column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have some data from https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/ which looks like:

```
Singapore,2020-04-17 23:30:32,1.2833,103.8333,5050,11,708,4331,Singapore
Singapore,2020-06-12 05:09:52,1.2833,103.8333,39387,25,27286,12076,Singapore,673.2425774010173,0.06347271942519106
```

When I read that with pandas, `sg = pd.read_csv("singapore.csv", names=["Country_Region", "Last_Update", "Lat", "Long", "Confirmed", "Deaths","Recovered","Active"])` it bizarrely looks like:

[image: Panda output]

It would look like the CSV is not properly read... why?

Bonus: How do I "clean" data that has added columns to a data structure like what has happened between [here](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/02-04-2020.csv) and [here](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/03-29-2020.csv).

https://github.com/kaihendry/covid19-sg/blob/master/pandas.ipynb

Comment: Perhaps the CSV has bad data, _somewhere_.  Does `read_csv` at least give you a line number when parsing fails?

Comment: You're going to need to be much more specific about your "bonus" question to get a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to tell pandas *not* to use the first column as the index by passing: `index_col=False` to your `read_csv()` call.

That will resolve the "bizarre" data.

Comment: Thanks! Any tips to make the Last_Update column a datetime type on read?

Comment: You may use `converters` parameter in `pandas` to convert a particular column to a certain datatype.